# How do i get true value

Tags: r

```
code:
x=table(sample_data$store_name=="35",sample_data$STATUS=="TERMINATED")
x

result:
        FALSE  TRUE
  FALSE 47232  1278
  TRUE    936   207
```

How can I only get the value 207?
I have tried other way but still can't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `sum` instead of `table` and combine the two conditions with `&`.

```
x = sum(sample_data$store_name=="35" & sample_data$STATUS=="TERMINATED")
```

---

Here's an example with built-in `mtcars` dataset to demonstrate -

```
table(mtcars$cyl == 4, mtcars$mpg > 30)
       
#        FALSE TRUE
#  FALSE    21    0
#  TRUE      7    4

sum(mtcars$cyl == 4 &  mtcars$mpg > 30)
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
x=table(sample_data$store_name=="35",
        sample_data$STATUS=="TERMINATED")[2,2]
```

Here treating `table` object as `matrix` .

Or for consistency we can use

```
x=table(sample_data$store_name=="35",
        sample_data$STATUS=="TERMINATED")["TRUE","TRUE"]
```